# Multil-class, Multi-label Object Detection using Tensorflow Keras in Google Colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, object-detection

My goal is the following:
I want to train an Object Detection model, which can classify multiple classes within an image.
Each of the classes can appear a varying number of times. It is also possible for different classes to appear within one image.

This is the model I am currently using:

```
def create_model(inShape, num_classes, optimizer):

    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=inShape)

    x = layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(input_layer)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)

    x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)

    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)

    x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

    x = layers.Flatten()(x)

    class_probs_layer = layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='class_Probs')(x)

    bbox_layer = layers.Dense(4, activation='linear', name='bboxes')(x)

    model = Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs=[class_probs_layer, bbox_layer])

    #Model kompilieren
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
          loss={'class_Probs': 'categorical_crossentropy',
              'bboxes': 'mean_squared_error'},
          metrics={'class_Probs': 'accuracy',
                   'bboxes': 'mean_squared_error'})

    return model
```

The output of the model is one bounding box (4 coordinates) and 2 probabilities, since right now I am training on a dataset with only 2 classes (caries, black stain).
P.S. the class_probs_layer has 4 outputs only for an error fix - otherwise logits and labels don't match.

Please suggest different model structure of some kind.

Also, my training is based on TFRecord-Files, which I wrote myself. I have one question regarding those:
Since there is multiple instances within in each image (but not the same number every time), there is 2 possibilities to write the TFRecords:

`image data, annotation, image data, annotation...` 
-> one instance for each bounding box, so multiple instances per image

OR

`image data, annotation, annotation, annotation, image data...` 
-> one instance per image, where the image data, which consists of image_id, filename and image_encoded, only appears once, and is followed by all the annotations (bounding boxes, category_ids) which belong to one image (image_id).